# Spring: How do I make sure Tomcat JDBC ConnectionPool can write logs

Tags: spring, tomcat, logging, jdbc, connection-pooling

I've set log-abandoned=true in a Spring Cloud service. However I don't see any

> Sep 04, 2015 6:39:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool abandon

logs. The application is pretty active so I think I should be seeing some stuff there. How can I make sure that the ConnectionPool is able to log? I have set the following properties' logging level to INFO from the Spring Boot Admin:

[image: Are these even the correct ones?]

Is that enough? Is there another property I need to set?

Also when the service starts up, I get this log:

> 11:46:20.194 [main] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker – Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

Could this be the reason why I don't see any logs?

Thanks so much for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to see if JDBC Connection Pool can write logs, because my app had no abandoned connections (he said braggingly).

The simplest way to make the Pool write some logs turned out to be just setting the maxIdle property something lesser than minIdle. Like 3 or something. Then it drops the following line of log:

```
WARNING: maxIdle is smaller than minIdle, setting maxIdle to: 10
```